# Sveltekit unable to build because there is a a <a> reference to a file under a folder

Tags: sveltekit

I have an `<a href="/resources/ink-archive/">` in a file named `resources.svelte`.

`resources.svelte` is directly under routes folder, while `resources/ink-archieve/` is under a subfolder routes/resouces/ink-archive.svelte.

This gives me an error when I try to build the project. Anyone knows a solution or why is the problem occurring. Its running locally.

Below is the error:

```
npm run build
    at Object.render (file:///home/client/.svelte-kit/output/server/app.js:93:20) > 500 /resources/ink-archive (linked from /resources) Error: 500 /resources/ink-archive (linked from /resources)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try move and rename `resources.svelte` to `resources/index.svelte`